# cuda sdk example simpleStreams in SDK 4.1 not working

Tags: cuda

I upgraded CUDA GPU computing SDK and CUDA computing toolkit to 4.1. I was testing simpleStreams programs, but consistently it is taking more time that non-streamed execution. my device is with compute capability 2.1 and i'm using VS2008,windows OS.

Comment: Windows 7 and CUDA drivers are one currently available on site

Comment: I confirm Windows is part of the issue - though I can't explain why for the time being. I have Win8 32bit and Ubuntu 12.04 32bit installed side-by-side on my desktop, with 2 GPUs (8800GTS and GTX660). The sample runs perfectly on Ubuntu (the traces show clear overlap between memCopy and kernel), while they fail to overlap on Win8.

Answer (score 1):

This sample constantly has issues. If you tweak the sample to have equal duration for the kernel and memory copy the overlap will improve. Normally breadth first submission is better for concurrency; however, on WDDM OS this sample will usually have better overlap if you issue the memory copy right after kernel launch.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this as well. I thought it was just me but I didn't notice any improvement and tried searching the forums but didn't find anyone else with the issue.

I also ran the source code in the Cuda By Example book (which is really helpful and I recommend you pick it up if you're serious about GPU programming).

Chapter 10 examples has the progression of examples showing how streams should be used.
http://developer.nvidia.com/content/cuda-example-introduction-general-purpose-gpu-programming-0

But comparing the,
1. non-streamed version(which is basically the single stream version)
2. the streamed (incorrectly queued asyncmemcpy and kernel launch)
3. the streamed (correctly queued asyncmemcpy and kernel launch)

I find no benefit in using cuda streams. It might be a win7 issue as I found some sources online discussing that win vista didn't support the cuda streams correctly.

Let me know what you find with the example I linked.  My setup is: Win7 64bit Pro, Cuda 4.1, Dual Geforce GTX460 cards, 8GB RAM.

Comment: I never thought that it could be Win7 issue, but let me check it on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to Cuda so may not be able to help but generally its very hard to help without you posting any code. If posting is not possible then I suggest you take a look at [Nvidia's visual profiler](http://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-visual-profiler).  Its cross platform and can show you were your bottlenecks are.

Comment: I'm trying to run from examples directory..so not my code..i think there is some bug in new code

Comment: check out the documentation for the code.  I'm not sure what examples directory your using but the one that was included in 'cuda by example' book had code that includes cpu versions and gpu versions, maybe you ran the cpu version by mistake?

Comment: no in src folder, i'm running simpleStreams example...streamed version is taking more time than non-streamed version, i don't know why it is happening?

Comment: @Lostsoul The sample program that the OP was referring to is including in the CUDA SDK.